# how can I reset the account stored for publishing a website on Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web, publish, credentials

I tried to publish a website from Visual Studio 2008 right clicking, Publish...

And I entered an invalid account and clicked "remember this ..."

So now I can't finish the publishing and I don't know how to reset that credential?

Any idea How can I change that account?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I did it following the "Windows Principle" - Turn Off and Turn On Windows

This is not the best approach, I still will love to know how to do it decently.